# how to send a message through socket connection from server when a endpoint of server is hit?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i need to send the message through socket connection that is already created when the endpoint of server is hit what is the way to do so, as I cannot send message directly because client from which socket connection is established is on localhost

edit - typo corrected

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


io.on('connection', function (socket){
   console.log('connection');
   socket.on('CH01', function (from, msg) {
   console.log('MSG', from, ' saying ', msg);
   socket.emit('CH01', 'me', 'test from server msg');

  });


});


app.post('/getUser', (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).send({
      success: 'false',
    message: 'title is required'

    });
  })


http.listen(9000, function () {
  console.log('listening on *:9000');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Above code is correct but there is a typo error in `socket1.emit('CH01', 'me', 'test from server msg')`.

`socket1.emit` should be `socket.emit`
As you are getting socket objects in the `socket` variable and `socket1` is undefined.

Comment: that was not the question, even considering the typo it doesnt solve my problem

Comment: @dj43 What is the actual issue?